# How to declare a TypeScript property to accept React class component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

There is a React component:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component<
  IMyComponentInterfaceWithProps
> { ... }
```

Now, in other place in the app, I would like to pass this component as follows:

```
routes = (<MyComponent />);
```

How to declare a type for routes object using TypeScript?

Something like:

```
let routes = typeof MyComponent // (this does not work!)
```

When I try the above I get an error:

> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type
> 'Pick<Readonly & Readonly<{ children?:
> ReactNode; }>, "IMyComponentInterfaceWithProp1" |
> "IMyComponentInterfaceWithProp2" |
> "IMyComponentInterfaceWithProp3" | ... 5 more ... | "children">':
> IMyComponentInterfaceWithProp4, IMyComponentInterfaceWithProp5,
> IMyComponentInterfaceWithProp6, IMyComponentInterfaceWithProp7, and 3
> more.",

Comment: Probably the Route component is not passing the props required

Comment: Can you provide more details? How did you use the `routes`? Which line raises this error?

Comment: You probably wanted to do something like `let routes: typeof MyComponent`. Also you could get a type of component with route props using `ComponentType` that is exported from `react`. Like this: `ComponentType<IMyComponentInterfaceWithProps>`